# Powershell how to convert System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary to PSCustomObject?

Tags: powershell

I have a System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary that I have obtained by running the code snippet below.  How do I convert $Obj to a PSCustomObject?

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")
$jsonserial= New-Object -TypeName System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$jsonserial.MaxJsonLength  = 67108864
$Obj = $jsonserial.DeserializeObject($JsonString)
```

Comment: Not sure how relevant this is, but do you know there's a `ConvertFrom-JSON` commandlet which returns PSCustomObjects?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, I exceeded the MaxJsonLength for the built-in ConvertFrom-JSON, so I used the JavaScriptSerializer to get past that limitation.  I'm loading a ~60MB JSON string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`New-Object` should work from PS 2.0 onwards:

```
$custom = new-object PSCustomObject -Property $obj
```

Comment: this also works.  When I tried last night, it didn't seem to, which is why I posted the question. I wanted to use the accelerator syntax, but this could be argued to be a "better" pure powershell answer.  Thanks for the answer and the reminder!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the following after the last line in the question

```
$Obj | ForEach-Object {
    $props = @{}
    $_.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        $props[$_.Key] = $_.Value
    }

    [PSCustomObject]$props
}
```

If there is a faster, shorter or better way, please feel free to answer

Comment: @mjolinor's solution should work e.g. `$obj | Foreach {[pscustomobject][hashtable]$_}`

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
$ht = @{}
$ht += $obj
[PSCustomObject]$ht
```

Edit:

V3 solution:

```
$ht = [collections.hashtable]$obj
[PSCustomObject]$ht
```

Comment: I am using PowerShell 3 and I can't seem to get the code above to work on line 2.  I get an InvalidOperation "A hash table can only be added to another hash table"

Comment: I'm using V4.  I just tested with V3 and I get that same error so apparently this is only going to work in V4+.  I'll poke at it a little more and see if I can find something else.

Comment: Posted an updated solution.  Tested in V3 emulation running under V4.

Comment: Thank you mjolinor!  I used the one line version that Keith Hill added as a comment to my answer.  Your answer (as a one line) was exactly what I was looking for.  Tested and works in V3